# Can I use ESP8266 and OV7670 to video stream on a web?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, programming, arduino-ide, electronics

OV7670 image sensor, small volume, low operating voltage, providing all functions of a single chip of VGA camera and image processor. so I am using and ESP8266 to connect to internet and stream the video from the OV7670 on a web, can I do so?

Comment: a quick search on the internet show that the camera can be used with an arduino, so the answer to your question is `yes`

Comment: @jsotola, but with esp8266 too? and can it be streamed on web, because most of the people are using the ESP32, but i want to do it with ESP8266, ESP32 can host a websocket, can ESP8266 do so too?

Comment: @jsotola and i am working with a NodeMCU

Comment: if it can be done on an arduino, its 99.9% sure it can be done on an ESP8266 when using arduino framework - also, the fact that you know you can do it on an ESP32 increases the probability of success to 99.99% - the only thing left is for you to do it - networking on ESP8266 is more mature than on ESP32, so in the case of networking, if it works in 32 it WILL work on an 8266

Comment: @JaromandaX and can i use the esp8266 to stream the ov7670 on web?

Comment: @JaromandaX , can you please give me any schematic on how to connect the Ov7670 to the nodemcu, because in an arduino we usually use 6 analog pins, where nodemcu only have one, so any idea? , thanks!

Comment: oh, sorry for leading you astray - I didn't think to look up the connections for you, thought you would've researched that yourself - it seems you can not connect that to an ESP, as there are far more pins to connect than the ESP actually has - I thought the question you had was about the functionality of the ESP, not the camera

Comment: @JaromandaX, no problem, so i cant use the esp8266 with the camera right?, ESP32 is only the way right?, can you please tell me , i need to know this, thanks!

Comment: google search `esp32 ov7670` and there are literally hundreds of working results - so, my guess is "yes"

Comment: @JaromandaX , yeah i know that it is working with esp32, but just wanted to know if i can use it with a cheaper microcontroller which is the nodemcu, but it seems you cant, thank you!